# Java solution for AST evaluation puzzle

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I got interested in [this discussion about AST construction and evaluation in various languages](https://gist.github.com/2934374). I am working on a solution in Java just to see what I can learn from this problem.

The code I have below compiles, but produces an incorrect result (namely an "oops" exception). It doesn't work because Java lacks runtime dispatch. Is there any simple workaround for that? How about complicated workarounds? E.g. using generics to give hints to the compiler? I'm just guessing here.

Some ideas that I've ruled out: (1) Use instanceof to dispatch by argument type at run time. (2) Build a look-up table which maps argument types to appropriate handlers. (3) Put an evaluation function in each subclass of E which evaluates that subclass appropriately.

I've ruled out (1) and (2) because I want to get the compiler and/or runtime to do that work for me. I've ruled out (3) because I want to separate the evaluation code from the expression representation; the idea being that there might be multiple operations (reordering, simplification) on the representation.

Here's what I have so far. As noted above, this code produces an incorrect result.

```
import java.util.*;

public class EV
{
    public static Integer ev (E e, Map <String, Integer> env) { throw new RuntimeException ("oops: " + e); }
    public static Integer ev (V e, Map <String, Integer> env) { return env.get (e.name); }
    public static Integer ev (C e, Map <String, Integer> env) { return e.value; }
    public static Integer ev (P e, Map <String, Integer> env) { return ev (e.a1, env) + ev (e.a2, env); }
    public static Integer ev (T e, Map <String, Integer> env) { return ev (e.a1, env) * ev (e.a2, env); }

    public static void main (String [] a)
    {
        E e = new P (new T (new C (2), new V ("a")), new V ("b"));
        Map <String, Integer> env = new Hashtable <String, Integer> ();
        env.put ("a", 123);
        env.put ("b", 456);
        System.out.println ("ev (e, env) => " + ev (e, env));
    }
}

class E {}

class V extends E
{
    String name;
    public V (String name) { this.name = name; }
}

class C extends E
{
    Integer value;
    public C (Integer value) { this.value = value; }
}

class P extends E
{
    E a1, a2;
    public P (E a1, E a2) { this.a1 = a1; this.a2 = a2; }
}

class T extends E
{
    E a1, a2;
    public T (E a1, E a2) { this.a1 = a1; this.a2 = a2; }
}
```

Comment: What about employing the Java precompiler and automatically generating dispatch methods (which could use `instanceof` etc.) for you? You'd need to write that code generator, however.

Comment: I still don't see what's wrong with #3.

Comment: I think #3 is fine too.  The dynamic dispatch can be done with polymorphism easily and all of the AST implementations I have seen in an OO language have an eval() method in each concrete class.  It makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, certainly, it will work if I put evaluation code into the expression classes. However, I am looking at this a little more abstractly: how can I separate the representation from operations on it? I am looking for a way to do that so that I don't have to modify the representation classes every time I want another operation.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you might use a single representation with multiple operations?  Just trying to wrap my head around it. Maybe you can add it to your example evaluator above.

Comment: @jeff: Some other operations on expressions that might be implemented in addition to evaluation: pretty-printing the expression in different ways (ascii art, TeX, MathML); replacing constant subexpressions with equivalent constants; applying algebraic identities; rearranging the expression to a canonical form.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - the first thing that popped in my head was Visitor as Don Ruby suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing this in a single-dispatch OO language like Java, this is a classic use-case for the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), especially if you are also interested in the pretty-print operations mentioned in your comment.  It might apply to some of the other operations mentioned in your comment, though they're a less natural fit.

Comment: Thanks, @Don. I am inclined to try to construct the visitor in such a way that it doesn't intrude on the expression classes. I suppose that necessarily means using reflection in the visitor to dispatch to a method suitable for whatever is currently being visited. I can live with that; the reflection stuff can go in a visitor base class, so even in visitor subclasses it wouldn't be a distraction.